# What Class determines Class Time Spent in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

If you play as a class in a Battlefield 3 map, obviously whatever class you spawn in as will receive time spent as that class towards the service medal. But what happens when you pick up another kit?

For example, if I spawn in as an Engineer, then run out of ammo and pick up a Recon kit, does my play time from then on go towards Engineer or Recon? I would think it would go towards Recon, however, visibly, my character will still appear to be an Engineer, just one holding a sniper rifle. This leads me to wonder which one actually receives the play time.

Comment: very good question indeed. Hope you don't spend so much time 'cross-classing'

Comment: Logically thinking, the kit you carry should determine the class your playing time goes to; otherwise, theoretically, one could balance his class time by spawning, killing one of his team-mates and picking up his stuff (just an example). Although, apparently, I'm [wrong](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/957916-battlefield-bad-company-2/answers?qid=169536).

Comment: You would think, but I would like to see a *Battlefield 3* reference.

Comment: I was under the impression that the points count towards the kit you're currently using. Which could be interesting because I suck with the recon kit.

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs that's not totally logical: if I'm a sniper in real life and I kill an engineer and start messing around with his tools, I'll be a sniper trying use engineering tools. I think BF works the same way

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo - but this is a *video game*, so in the game, what he said makes logical sense

Comment: BF doesn't look like the game that would allow that :) It's still a war simulation that tries to be as real as possible (except that you can eject from a flying vehicle and stab people to death while falling)

Comment: My point is that because it's a video game, even though it tries to be realistic, the logic behind statistics and tracking is more than likely logical from a video game point of view, rather than a "real-life" point of view

Answer (score 2):

The class timer is ALWAYS determined by the class chosen when spawning. The server takes this data and starts the timer.
You create a profile on the server when joining a server, with default class = Assault (that's why you see assault as the first class "already chosen"). You cannot log in to the server unless this profile has data on it. (assault, and all values = 0)

When you see the scoreboard, the server creates that data from each of the player's profile. If you see a little wrench, cross, crosshair or bullets, then you know what is going to be taken into account when adding time to a class.

Comment: Sounds good, but can you source this?

Comment: Does everything have to have a source?

Comment: @Timtech - Yep. I could just make up something like this, and say it's so, and it might not be

Comment: @SSumner yeah, my source is experience playing... i just tested this for you, and the time on the battlelog keeps adding to my initially chosen class, rather than the kit I picked...